# enqueue script during add menu items means before save menu items

Tags: menus, admin-menu

I'm extended the `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit` class and added some new custom fields based on some jQuery plugins like (wpColorPicker, fonIconPicker, and Select2). I'm called these functions from different js file like below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.fonticons-iconwpcolorpicker').wpColorPicker();

$(".hpemenu-fonticons-size").TouchSpin({
    min: 12,
    max: 100,
    stepinterval: 50,
    maxboostedstep: 1000,
    postfix: 'px'
});

$(".hpemenu-itemesnum").TouchSpin({
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        stepinterval: 50,
        maxboostedstep: 1000,
        postfix: 'Items or posts'
});

$(".bsnselect").select2({
    placeholder: "Select ...",
    width: '100%',
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    theme: "classic"
});

var hpemenuFontIcons = $('.hpemenu-fonticons').fontIconPicker({
    theme: 'fip-bootstrap'
});
$.ajax( {
    url: hpemenu_ajax_object.fontIconsJsonUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
} )
.done( function( response ) {
    hpemenuFontIcons.setIcons( response );
} );

$('a.item-edit').click(function() {
    var itemId = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
    var menuItemType = $('#' + itemId + ' .field-menuitem-type input');
    var defaultMenu = $('#' + itemId + ' .bsnavbar-default');
    var advanceMenu = $('#' + itemId + ' .bsnavbar-advance');
    var urlInput = $('#' + itemId + ' .bsn-menuitem-url');
    var bsnAdditionalSection = $('#' + itemId + ' .bsn-menuitem-additional');

    var showHideMenuItem = function() {
        var menuItemValue = $('#' + itemId + ' .field-menuitem-type input:checked').val();
        if (menuItemValue === 'defaultmenu') {
            defaultMenu.add(urlInput).add(bsnAdditionalSection).show();
            advanceMenu.hide();
        } else if (menuItemValue === 'advancemenu') {
            advanceMenu.add(defaultMenu).show();
            urlInput.add(bsnAdditionalSection).hide();
        } else {
            defaultMenu.add(advanceMenu).hide();
        }
    };
    showHideMenuItem();
    menuItemType.on('change', showHideMenuItem);


    var menuItemLayoutCheckboxes = $('#' + itemId + ' .field-menuitemlayouts input');
    var menuItemName = $('#' + itemId + ' .bsn-menuitem-name');
    var fontIconsSection = $('#' + itemId + ' .menuitem-fonticons');

    var menuItemLayoutsFunc = function() {
        var menuItemLayoutChecked = $('#' + itemId + ' .field-menuitemlayouts input:checked').val();
        if ( menuItemLayoutChecked === 'itemwithouticon' ) {
            fontIconsSection.hide();
            menuItemName.show();
        } else if ( menuItemLayoutChecked === 'itemicon' ) {
            menuItemName.hide();
            fontIconsSection.show();
        } else {
            fontIconsSection.add(menuItemName).show();
        }
    };
    menuItemLayoutsFunc();
    menuItemLayoutCheckboxes.on( 'change', menuItemLayoutsFunc);

    var contentType = $('#' + itemId + ' .field-content-type input');
    var uniformBox = $('#' + itemId + ' p.uniform-title, #' + itemId + ' p.field-uniform');
    var uniformSelect = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-uniform select');
    var customCat = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-custom-cat');
    var customTag = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-custom-tag');
    var customCatsTab = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-custom-cats-tab');
    var customTagsTab = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-custom-tags-tab');
    var customTagsOfCat = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-custom-tags-of-cat-tab');
    var gridLayout = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-items-grid');
    var itemsNumber = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-items-num');

    var showHideCatTagTab = function() {
        uniformSelect.find('option:selected').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('value') === 'custom-cat') {
                customCat.show();
                customTag.add(customCatsTab).add(customTagsTab).add(customTagsOfCat).hide();
            } else if ($(this).attr('value') === 'custom-tag') {
                customTag.show();
                customCat.add(customCatsTab).add(customTagsTab).add(customTagsOfCat).hide();
            } else if ($(this).attr('value') === 'custom-cats-tab') {
                customCatsTab.show();
                customCat.add(customTag).add(customTagsTab).add(customTagsOfCat).hide();
            } else if ($(this).attr('value') === 'custom-tags-tab') {
                customTagsTab.show();
                customCat.add(customTag).add(customCatsTab).hide();
            } else if ($(this).attr('value') === 'custom-tags-of-cat-tab') {
                customTagsOfCat.show();
                customTag.add(customCat).add(customCatsTab).add(customTagsTab).hide();
            } else {
                customCat.add(customTag).add(customCatsTab).add(customTagsTab).add(customTagsOfCat).hide();
            }
            if ($(this).attr('value') === 'contact' || $(this).attr('value') === 'search') {
                itemsNumber.add(gridLayout).hide();
            } else {
                itemsNumber.add(gridLayout).show();
            }
        });
    };
    showHideCatTagTab();
    uniformSelect.on('change', showHideCatTagTab);

    var multipleBox = $('#' + itemId + ' p.multiple-title, #' + itemId + ' p.field-multiple');
    var multipleSelect = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-multiple select');
    var customCategory = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-custom-category');
    var customTags = $('#' + itemId + ' p.field-custom-tags');
    var categoryFlag = false;
    var tagFlag = false;
    var itemsFalg = false;

    var showHideCatTag = function() {
        multipleSelect.find('option:selected').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('value') === 'custom-category') {
               categoryFlag = true;
            }
            if ($(this).attr('value') === 'custom-tags') {
               tagFlag = true;
            }
        });
        if(categoryFlag && tagFlag) {
            customCategory.add(customTags).show();
            categoryFlag = false;
            tagFlag = false;
        } else if(categoryFlag && !tagFlag) {
            customCategory.show();
            customTags.hide();
            categoryFlag = false;
            tagFlag = false;
        } else if(!categoryFlag && tagFlag) {
            customCategory.hide();
            customTags.show();
            categoryFlag = false;
            tagFlag = false;
        } else {
            customCategory.add(customTags).hide();
            categoryFlag = false;
            tagFlag = false;
        }
    };
    showHideCatTag();
    multipleSelect.on('change', showHideCatTag);

    var showHideUniMul = function() {
        var contentTypeValue = $('#' + itemId + ' .field-content-type input:checked').val();
        if (contentTypeValue === 'uniform') {
            uniformBox.show();
            showHideCatTagTab();
            multipleBox.hide(function() {
                customCategory.add(customTags).hide();
            });
        } else if (contentTypeValue === 'multiple') {
            multipleBox.show();
            showHideCatTag();
            uniformBox.hide(function() {
                customCat.add(customTag).add(customCatsTab).add(customTagsTab).add(customTagsOfCat).hide();
            });
        } else {
            uniformBox.add(multipleBox).hide();
        }
    };
    showHideUniMul();
    contentType.on('change', showHideUniMul);

});

});
```

Then I enqueued this js file over my Wordpress admin area by using `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.

When I add new menu item from `Custom Link` panel, these functions not work until I Click on `Save Menu` button to save menu item, After saving menu item and reload the `nav-menus.php` all functions work without the problem.

**INFO:** When I use jQuery functions inside the `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit`Class (Means not in separate js file) inside `<script></script>` tag all functions work before saving menu item.

How can I call js file inside the `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit`? Or how can I trigger js file codes during adding custom link items before saving menu items?

Comment: @Shibi Sorry I put the `itemId` and `menuItemType` outside the `click` event now I've updated the code. I have more functions and events related to the `select2` jquery plugin within my js file, but in my question only I put some codes until my question clear to you. Now only I want my code work during adding items and after saving items.

Comment: @Shibi I used the updated code also the  code inside the `$('body').on('click', 'a.item-edit', function() {});` only work after the saving menu items and not work during adding menu item

Comment: @ShibiI updated my code and I put all codes in my js file related to my menu items. All codes work perfectly after saving menu items. Only I want the codes to work and functions trigger during adding menu items before saving the items. I know you very tired with my question. Thanks for helping

Comment: I have updated my code and tested its now working the `jQuery.on` didn't worked well so I changed it to a function thats run when you click. Its working well in all conditions.

Comment: This JavaScript. No connection with WordPress.

Comment: @MaxYudin Yeah the event `document#menu-item-added` its the only thing that really have a connection right now :/

Comment: @MaxYudin why you put downvote? I'm asked for Help. My code works with my Wordpress plugin without any problem. How you know not work? But I want during adding item trigger my codes. Do you read my question?

Comment: @Shibi Thanks for your reply i thnink must be now work I'm understand the basic of using the code within your code I try then back to tell you about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this menu items are appended with ajax response you need to run this JS functions again for each item that you add to the menu with the `document#menu-item-added` event.

Add something like this in your JS file.

```
$(document).on('menu-item-added', function(event, markup) {
    // debug that the hook work
    console.log(markup);
    $.each(markup, function(index, menuItem) {
        if(menuItem.id) {
            // check menu item html markup
            console.log(menuItem);
            $('#' + menuItem.id).find('.hpemenu-fonticons').fontIconPicker();
            $('#' + menuItem.id).find('.fonticons-iconwpcolorpicker').wpColorPicker();
            $('#' + menuItem.id).find('.bsnselect').select2();
        }
    });
});
```

Add click event with function to run where you click in the document ready and in after menu item added.

So Your code should look like this:

```
jQuery.(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.hpemenu-fonticons').fontIconPicker();
    $('.fonticons-iconwpcolorpicker').wpColorPicker();
    $(".bsnselect").select2();

    // Add click event
    $('a.item-edit').click(some_function);

    $(document).on('menu-item-added', function(event, markup) {
        // debug that the hook work
        console.log(markup);
        $.each(markup, function(index, menuItem) {
            if(menuItem.id) {
                // check menu item html markup
                console.log(menuItem);
                $('#' + menuItem.id).find('.hpemenu-fonticons').fontIconPicker();
                $('#' + menuItem.id).find('.fonticons-iconwpcolorpicker').wpColorPicker();
                $('#' + menuItem.id).find('.bsnselect').select2();

                // Add click event
                $('#' + menuItem.id).find('a.item-edit').click(some_function);
            }
        });
    });

    function some_function() {
        var itemId = $(this).closest('li').attr('id'),
            menuItemType = $('#' + itemId + ' .field-menuitem-type input');

        var showHideMenuItem = function() {
            //Some codes here
        };
        showHideMenuItem();
        menuItemType.on('change', showHideMenuItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: I used your code but still, the functions not working during add menu items also must Save Menu until working. But I noticed that From Inspect->Network When to add new custom link menu item only admin-ajax.php load. But when click on Save Menu to save items I see the select2.js, fonticonpicker.js, and other plugins load. I think must find the way to load these plugins during adding menu items before click on Save Menu button.

Comment: Why when i use the jQuery codes insode the Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit class all plugin functions work during add items? but when i use them inside the separate the js file not work?

Comment: @ShwanNamiq First you need to load the select2.js and fonticonpicker.js and your custom js file in the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook. About the why its because the js is loaded inline and will run when its append to the document.

Comment: I've enqueued the plugins by using admin_enqueue_scripts hook action I don't have the problem with this. I think I enqueued all of them correctly because after Save Menu all functions working.

Comment: Thanks so much now every thing it is Ok. I have this problem for more that 8 monthes i asked more than 10 times in more forums i don't get the correct answer after all these attemts i get the correct answer thanks a lot you helped me

Comment: @ShwanNamiq No problem. good luck!

Comment: I have a small problem your code only work during adding the new item. After saving menu items the functions do not work. I want the functions to work during adding items and after saving items.

Comment: I have some functions related to the jQuery functions like `var showHideMenuItem = function() {};` and `$('a.item-edit').click(function() {});` How can use them within your code?

Comment: Must Means I use the functions two times one within your code another outside your code?

Comment: I updated my code I'm added some codes you can see them. But I have more codes related to the jquery functions if I use two times one time within your code and another time outside your code I think it is a bad idea about duplicating all these codes. Did have another way until code work during adding items and after saving items?